How Can I fix the issues running Coroutine on Unity's Touch in mobile
I'm new in Unity and C#.And I have some problems. When my character moves using a 'touchmove', I used a 'weapon' to launch a 'projectilePrefab'.
However, when I actually touched and moved the character, I had a problem that the "projectilePrefab" was fired too fast.
Help me PLZZZZZZZZ
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject projectilePrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private float attackRate = 0.5f;

    
    public void StartFiring()
    {
        StartCoroutine("TryAttack");
    }

    public void StopFiring()
    {
        StopCoroutine("TryAttack");
    }

    private IEnumerator TryAttack()
    {
        while ( true)
        {
            Instantiate(projectilePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackRate);
        }
    }

   
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TouchMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 touchPosition;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector3 direction;
    private float moveSpeed = 10f;
    private Weapon weapon;

    private void Awake() 
    {
       weapon = GetComponent<Weapon>();    
    }

    private void Start() 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            touchPosition.z = 0;
            direction = (touchPosition - transform.position);
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y) * moveSpeed;
            weapon.StartFiring();

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                weapon.StopFiring();
        }
    }
}

I want to make sure that the launch speed of "projectilePrefab" is fired at 0.5f, which is the launch speed I set.

Based on it firing too fast, you're probably starting more than 1 instance of the TryAttack() Coroutine. Here are a few things that should help.

StopCoroutine("TryAttack") is only going to stop the first coroutine that it finds. If you have more than 1 running, it wont stop all of them.
StartCoroutine() is unguarded, it is possible for it to start many coroutines and since you aren't storing them anywhere, they will be harder to reference.
It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do with Input.touchCount. Update() runs every frame so weapon.StartFiring() is running many times, while weapson.StopFiring() is only running once on the touch end. Unity has examples that will be helpful in thedocumentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html.

From the docs - Try using TouchPhase.Began to Start firing and TouchPhase.Ended to stop.
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        // Start Firing
        weapon.StartFiring();
    }

    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        // Stop Firing
        weapon.StopFiring();
    }
}

Consider something like this to prevent weapon from starting more coroutines than intended.
public class Weapon : Monobehavior 
{
    private Coroutine FireRoutine;

    public void StartFiring() 
    {
        if (FireRoutine == null)
            FireRoutine = StartCoroutine("TryAttack");
    }

    public void StopFiring() 
    {
        if (FireRoutine != null) 
        {
            StopCoroutine(FireRoutine);
            FireRoutine = null;
        }
    }
}

